# Disable Jetpack Compose in Release Build

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

We have an app which has an user interface (`DebugActivity`) when we build the variant `debug` and should come without UI when we build the variant `release`.
This does not work unfortunately and fails with:

```
androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.IncompatibleComposeRuntimeVersionException: The Compose Compiler requires the Compose Runtime to be on the class path, but none could be found. The compose compiler plugin you are using (version 1.5.3) expects a minimum runtime version of 1.0.0.
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.noRuntimeOnClasspathError(VersionChecker.kt:172)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.check(VersionChecker.kt:149)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$lambda$1(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:222)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:255)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.convertToIr(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:224)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:460)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:476)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:399)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:280)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:636)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1598)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

We tried to disable compose by configuring our `build.gradle.kts` like you can see below.
We also removed the suggested use of `platform()` for getting the compose bom and referenced all needed dependencies manually.

build.gradle.kts (app):

```
android {
   buildTypes {
           release {
               isMinifyEnabled = false
               signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
               proguardFiles(
                   getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                   "proguard-rules.pro"
               )
               buildFeatures {
                   compose = false
               }
           }
           debug {
               buildFeatures {
                    compose = true
               }
               composeOptions {
                   kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = versions.kotlinCompilerExtension
               }
           }
       }
   }

dependencies {
    // Android
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)

    // Android Compose
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.material3)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.activity)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.viewmodel)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.datastore.preferences)

    // Testing
    testImplementation(libs.junit4)
 
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.core)

    // generate kotlin doc
    dokkaPlugin(libs.dokka)
}
```

What am I missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated. <3

Comment: You need to remove all lib reference of Compose

Comment: But we want to be able to build a `debug` variant with compose included and a `release` variant without compose.